# effect of floating point precision in testing if a varable attains a bound

Tags: c++, loops, testing, precision

I have a C/C++ function checkt (FLT t) where FLT is the floating point precison set by the preprocessor that I want to use in a much bigger body of code to ensure that values passed to it are in the range [0,1]. It is often used in increasing a variable by fixed increments checkt trips an error when the argument is out of range. In this simple example I want to go from 0.0 to 1.0 in ten increments of 0.1. However since 0.1 is not represented perfectly as 0.1000000000 etc to the limit of precision and then I will attain exactly the value 1.0 at the end of the loop. The code snippet below works if FLT is set to double but not if it is set to float. I also append the output from both. The compiler is gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define FLT double

void checkt (FLT t) {
    if (t < FLT{0} || t > FLT{1}) {
        std::cout << "t before error = " << t << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error ("t out of range [0,1]");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FLT x = FLT{0.0};
    FLT inc = FLT{0.1};
    FLT y = FLT{1};

    std::cout.precision(16);
    std::cout << "x is " << x << "y is " << y << " inc is " << inc << std::endl;

    for (int i=0; i<11; i++){ 
        std::cout.precision(16);
        std::cout << "x is " << x << std::endl;
        checkt(x);
        x += inc;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output with FLT=double x is 0y is 1 inc is 0.1

```
x is 0
x is 0.1
x is 0.2
x is 0.3
x is 0.4
x is 0.5
x is 0.6
x is 0.7
x is 0.7999999999999999
x is 0.8999999999999999
x is 0.9999999999999999
```

output with FLT = float is

```
y is 1 inc is 0.1000000014901161
x is 0
x is 0.1000000014901161
x is 0.2000000029802322
x is 0.300000011920929
x is 0.4000000059604645
x is 0.5
x is 0.6000000238418579
x is 0.7000000476837158
x is 0.8000000715255737
x is 0.9000000953674316
x is 1.00000011920929
t before error = 1.00000011920929
terminate called after throwing an inst
```

Comment: The function `check` is not valid C.  You should remove the C tag, add a C++ tag, and remove the expression `C/C++` from your question.  This is pure C++.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You could use interpolation, setting `x = (FLT)i / (FLT)10;` instead of incrementing by an inexact value.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the imprecise nature of binary floating point, the repeated addition in each iteration of the loop can result in an error factor accumulating over time.

Rather than adding the increment amount to `x` on each iteration, multiply the increment  by the loop index and set `x` to that.

```
for (int i=0; i<11; i++){
    x = inc * i;
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cout << "x is " << x << std::endl;
    checkt(x);
}
```

Output for `double`:

```
x is 0y is 1 inc is 0.1
x is 0
x is 0.10000000000000001
x is 0.20000000000000001
x is 0.30000000000000004
x is 0.40000000000000002
x is 0.5
x is 0.60000000000000009
x is 0.70000000000000007
x is 0.80000000000000004
x is 0.90000000000000002
x is 1
```

Output for `float`:

```
x is 0y is 1 inc is 0.1000000014901161
x is 0
x is 0.10000000149011612
x is 0.20000000298023224
x is 0.30000001192092896
x is 0.40000000596046448
x is 0.5
x is 0.60000002384185791
x is 0.69999998807907104
x is 0.80000001192092896
x is 0.90000003576278687
x is 1
```

Comment: Re: “the imprecise nature of binary floating point” — floating point arithmetic, binary, decimal, or otherwise, is exact. It is **not** arithmetic on **real numbers**, so the results are not the same as you’d get with real numbers. Working with floating-point numbers requires dealing with them as they exist, not treating them as sloppy real numbers. +1.

Comment: Many apologies to dbush, the example of using the loop index variable to remove the progressively increasing error solves the problem I posed. However in the original problem from which I derived it we are adding increments to a variable that should not exceed 1 but can reach it. These increments are set by other calculations in the program and so are not uniform with the loop variable. So I chose an incomplete simplification of the problem,

Comment: I mean apologies for my being so slow to respond.